# Convert spark DataFrame column to python list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I work on a dataframe with two column, mvv and count.

```
+---+-----+
|mvv|count|
+---+-----+
| 1 |  5  |
| 2 |  9  |
| 3 |  3  |
| 4 |  1  |
```

i would like to obtain two list containing mvv values and count value. Something like

```
mvv = [1,2,3,4]
count = [5,9,3,1]
```

So, I tried the following code: The first line should return a python list of row. I wanted to see the first value:

```
mvv_list = mvv_count_df.select('mvv').collect()
firstvalue = mvv_list[0].getInt(0)
```

But I get an error message with the second line:

> AttributeError: getInt

Comment: As of Spark 2.3, this code is the fastest and least likely to cause OutOfMemory exceptions: `list(df.select('mvv').toPandas()['mvv'])`.  [Arrow was integrated into PySpark](https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2017/07/26/spark-arrow/) which sped up `toPandas` significantly.  Don't use the other approaches if you're using Spark 2.3+.  See my answer for more benchmarking details.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

See, why this way that you are doing is not working. First, you are trying to get integer from a [Row](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row) Type, the output of your collect is like this:

```
>>> mvv_list = mvv_count_df.select('mvv').collect()
>>> mvv_list[0]
Out: Row(mvv=1)
```

If you take something like this:

```
>>> firstvalue = mvv_list[0].mvv
Out: 1
```

You will get the `mvv` value. If you want all the information of the array you can take something like this:

```
>>> mvv_array = [int(row.mvv) for row in mvv_list.collect()]
>>> mvv_array
Out: [1,2,3,4]
```

But if you try the same for the other column, you get:

```
>>> mvv_count = [int(row.count) for row in mvv_list.collect()]
Out: TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

This happens because `count` is a built-in method. And the column has the same name as `count`. A workaround to do this is change the column name of `count` to `_count`:

```
>>> mvv_list = mvv_list.selectExpr("mvv as mvv", "count as _count")
>>> mvv_count = [int(row._count) for row in mvv_list.collect()]
```

But this workaround is not needed, as you can access the column using the dictionary syntax:

```
>>> mvv_array = [int(row['mvv']) for row in mvv_list.collect()]
>>> mvv_count = [int(row['count']) for row in mvv_list.collect()]
```

And it will finally work!

Comment: it works great for the first column, but it does not work for the column count i think because of (the function count of spark)

Comment: Can you add what are you doing with the count? Add here in the comments.

Comment: thanks for your response 
So this line work 

mvv_list = [int(i.mvv) for i in mvv_count.select('mvv').collect()]

but not this one

count_list = [int(i.count) for i in mvv_count.select('count').collect()]
return invalid syntax

Comment: Don't need to add this `select('count')` use like this: `count_list = [int(i.count) for i in mvv_list.collect()]` I will add the example to the response.

Comment: this line count_list = [int(i.count) for i in mvv_list.collect()] also return: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

Comment: How do you instanciate your `mvv_list`?

Comment: mvv_list result of many transformation of an initial dataframe. The tab print in my question result of mvv_list.show().

Comment: #Thiago Baldim
i found a solution but it not elegant
count_list = [i[1] for i in mvv_list.collect()]
it work because i know that count at index = 2.
Do youknow a solution which allow you to precise the column name 'count' despite of the index ?

Comment: It should work with i.count. Really strange... Do something... Add here in the comments the `mvv_list.collect()` that I will be able to understande the issue.

Comment: here is the line where i instantiate mvv_list:              mvv_list = mvv_logs.groupBy('mvv').count()

Comment: I added a solution above in the answer.

Comment: @a.moussa `[i.['count'] for i in mvv_list.collect()]` works to make it explicit to use the column named 'count' and not the `count` function

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim I want to access column value where column is month like 202111 which is variable and whose name is coming from another list. I am trying something like 'list[0].i.Month' which is not working. So i.Month is inside for loop whose value is changing in each iteration like 202111, 202112 and so on. can you please help me how to access it

Answer (score 190):

Following one liner gives the list you want.

```
mvv = mvv_count_df.select("mvv").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
```

Comment: Performance wise this solution is much faster than your solution mvv_list = [int(i.mvv) for i in mvv_count.select('mvv').collect()]

Comment: Wouldn't this just work for OP's question?: mvv = mvv_count_df.select("mvv").rdd.flatMap(list).collect()

Answer (score 46):

This will give you all the elements as a list.

```
mvv_list = list(
    mvv_count_df.select('mvv').toPandas()['mvv']
)
```

Comment: This is the fastest and most efficient solution for Spark 2.3+.  See the benchmarking results in my answer.

Answer (score 42):

I ran a benchmarking analysis and `list(mvv_count_df.select('mvv').toPandas()['mvv'])` is the fastest method.  I'm very surprised.

I ran the different approaches on 100 thousand / 100 million row datasets using a 5 node i3.xlarge cluster (each node has 30.5 GBs of RAM and 4 cores) with Spark 2.4.5.  Data was evenly distributed on 20 snappy compressed Parquet files with a single column.

Here's the benchmarking results (runtimes in seconds):

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|                          Code                               | 100,000 | 100,000,000 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+
| df.select("col_name").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()    |     0.4 | 55.3        |
| list(df.select('col_name').toPandas()['col_name'])          |     0.4 | 17.5        |
| df.select('col_name').rdd.map(lambda row : row[0]).collect()|     0.9 | 69          |
| [row[0] for row in df.select('col_name').collect()]         |     1.0 | OOM         |
| [r[0] for r in mid_df.select('col_name').toLocalIterator()] |     1.2 | *           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+

* cancelled after 800 seconds
```

Golden rules to follow when collecting data on the driver node:

- Try to solve the problem with other approaches.  Collecting data to the driver node is expensive, doesn't harness the power of the Spark cluster, and should be avoided whenever possible.
- Collect as few rows as possible.  Aggregate, deduplicate, filter, and prune columns before collecting the data.  Send as little data to the driver node as you can.

`toPandas` [was significantly improved in Spark 2.3](https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2017/07/26/spark-arrow/).  It's probably not the best approach if you're using a Spark version earlier than 2.3.

See [here](https://mungingdata.com/pyspark/column-to-list-collect-tolocaliterator/) for more details / benchmarking results.

Comment: This really is surprising since I would imagined `toPandas` to perform one of the worst since we are doing an additional data structure transformation. Spark team must have really done good job with optimization. Thanks for the benchmark!

Comment: Could you also test the @phgui answer?
It also looks quite efficient.
`mvv_list   = df.select(collect_list("mvv")).collect()[0][0]`

Answer (score 24):

On my data I got these benchmarks:

```
>>> data.select(col).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
```

0.52 sec

```
>>> [row[col] for row in data.collect()]
```

0.271 sec

```
>>> list(data.select(col).toPandas()[col])
```

0.427 sec

The result is the same

Comment: If you use `toLocalIterator` instead of `collect` it should even be more memory efficient `[row[col] for row in data.toLocalIterator()]`

Answer (score 21):

The following code will help you

```
mvv_count_df.select('mvv').rdd.map(lambda row : row[0]).collect()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. the reason is that you are staying in a spark context throughout the process and then you collect at the end as opposed to getting out of the spark context earlier which may cause a larger collect depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 8):

A possible solution is using the `collect_list()` function from `pyspark.sql.functions`. This will aggregate all column values into a pyspark array that is converted into a python list when collected:

```py
mvv_list   = df.select(collect_list("mvv")).collect()[0][0]
count_list = df.select(collect_list("count")).collect()[0][0]
```

Answer (score 8):

you can first collect the df with will return list of Row type

```
row_list = df.select('mvv').collect()
```

iterate over row to convert to list

```
sno_id_array = [ int(row.mvv) for row in row_list]

sno_id_array 
[1,2,3,4]
```

**using flatmap**

```
sno_id_array = df.select("mvv").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
```

Answer (score 7):

Let's create the dataframe in question

```
df_test = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 5),
        (2, 9),
        (3, 3),
        (4, 1),
    ],
    ['mvv', 'count']
)
df_test.show()
```

Which gives

```
+---+-----+
|mvv|count|
+---+-----+
|  1|    5|
|  2|    9|
|  3|    3|
|  4|    1|
+---+-----+
```

and then apply rdd.flatMap(f).collect() to get the list

```
test_list = df_test.select("mvv").rdd.flatMap(list).collect()
print(type(test_list))
print(test_list)
```

which gives

```
<type 'list'>
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you get the error below :

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'collect'

This code will solve your issues :

```
mvv_list = mvv_count_df.select('mvv').collect()

mvv_array = [int(i.mvv) for i in mvv_list]
```

Comment: I got that error too and this solution solved the problem. But why did I get the error? (Many others don't seem to get that!)

Answer (score 5):

Despite many answeres, some of them wont work when you need a list to be used in combination with `when` and `isin` commands. The simplest yet effective approach resulting a flat list of values is by using list comprehension and `[0]` to avoid row names:

```
flatten_list_from_spark_df=[i[0] for i in df.select("your column").collect()]
```

The other approach is to use panda data frame and then use the `list` function but it is not convenient and as effective as this.a

Comment: This is the best answer. RDDs are becoming outdated and are hard to use.