# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence when plotting line chart using pyspark in zeppelin

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, linechart, valueerror

Currently I have this dataframe(df):

```
    +-------------------+--------+
    |       datetime_new|pkts_new|
    +-------------------+--------+
    |2018-01-04 00:00:00|    47.0|
    |2018-01-04 00:00:00|     1.0|
    |2018-01-04 00:00:00|     3.0|
    |2018-01-04 00:00:00|    40.0|
    |2018-01-04 00:01:00|     1.0|
    |2018-01-04 00:01:00|     1.0|
    |2018-01-04 00:01:00|     1.0|
    |2018-01-04 00:01:00|    49.0|
    |2018-01-04 00:01:00|    33.0|
    |2018-01-04 00:01:00|     2.0|
    +-------------------+--------+

`DataFrame[datetime_new: timestamp, pkts_new: double]`

type(t): <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
```

I want to plot a line chart where the x axis is datetime_new, and the y axis is pkts_new. However, when i used this command:
`plt.plot(df.select('datetime_new'),df.select('pkts_new'))` ,
 I will get the error message:`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`.

How do I plot a line chart for  ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert array into list using list(myarray)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
plt.plot(data_time,time)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If i were to type `plt.plot(list(df.select("datetime_new")),list(df.select("pkts_new")))`, the error will still be the same

Comment: convert the array in list at prior stage during plotting it will not convert to list, and plotting needs list for axis

Comment: `t_dt = list(df.select("datetime_new"))
t_pkt = list(df.select("pkts_new"))
plt.plot(t_dt , t_pkt)
plt.show()` wil still give me the same error message. can u show me an example please? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22341390/4683899 refer this link for conversion

Comment: plt.plot(df['datetime_new'].tolist(),df['pkts_new'].tolist()) I guess this will help

Comment: TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable, because my dataframe is not pandas. is pyspark sql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49123695/4683899 this is conversion of pysark into list