# Reading Row values in DataBricks Notebook

Tags: azure-databricks

I have a Databricks python notebook reading ADL configurations from a JSON file on DBFS. I am able to read the file fine and the DF generated shows the values with the below schema.

```
testJsonData:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame

clientId:string
oauth2Credential:string
oauth2RefreshUrl:string
providerType:string
```

I am having challenges in reading a specific row value. I am getting a row object but doesn't give me the value of the row.

```
testJsonData.select('clientId').collect()
Out[65]: [Row(clientId='6xxxx08vvvvvvvvv7f')]
```

Appreciate any pointers helping with this.

Comment: I found the solution in another article - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38610559/convert-spark-dataframe-column-to-python-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps someone having a similar issue, I read the config values like this

```
   configlist = testJsonData.select("*").collect()
   dataProviderType = configlist[0].providerType
   dataClientId = configlist[0].clientId
   dataOAuthCredential = configlist[0].oauth2Credential
   dataOAuthUrl = configlist[0].outh2RefreshUrl
```