# How Can I replace value if IS NOT IN a list?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list with all values distinct in a column and I need to replace all values that IS NOT IN this list with 1

I've tried this

```
uniq = X_train3.select('street').distinct().collect()
X_test3 = X_test3.withColumn('street', F.when(array_contains('street', uniq), 1))
```

and i also tried this:

```
uniq = X_train3.select('street').distinct().collect()
X_test3 = X_test3.withColumn('street', F.when(~col('street').isin(uniq), 1))
```

both result in this error: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [[1.0]]

This is what I did in python and works:

```py
uniq = X_train3[cl].unique()
uniq = uniq.tolist()
X_test3['street'] = X_test3['street'].map(lambda x: 1 if x not in uniq else x)]
```

Comment: See this question on how to collect column values into a list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38610559/convert-spark-dataframe-column-to-python-list

Answer (score -1):

You can do this (in Scala, write the equivalent pyspark):

```
val new_X_test3 = X_test3
.join(X_train3
    .select("street")
    .distinct()
    .withColumnRenamed("street","street_train"), 
    col("street") === col("street_train"), 
    "leftouter")
.withColumn("street_test", 
    when(col("street_train").isNull, lit("1"))
    .otherwise(col("street")))
.drop("street","street_train")
.withColumnRenamed("street_test","street")
```

Also if you're convinced that the list of unique streets is very small (since you tried collecting it on the driver in your code) you can provide the `broadcast`hint around `X_train3`. So code becomes:

```
val new_X_test3 = X_test3
.join(broadcast(X_train3
    .select("street")
    .distinct()
    .withColumnRenamed("street","street_train")), 
    col("street") === col("street_train"), 
    "leftouter")
.withColumn("street_test", 
    when(col("street_train").isNull, lit("1"))
    .otherwise(col("street")))
.drop("street","street_train")
.withColumnRenamed("street_test","street")
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It answers the question precisely.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it seems abundantly clear that the question is about PySpark, not Spark, and therefore your answer does not directly address the issue.