# to string method in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a code in pyspark. I need to convert it to string then convert it to date type, etc.

I can't find any method to convert this type to string. I tried str(), .to_string(), but none works. I put the code below.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = in_df.select('COL1')
```

```
> type(df) 
> <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>

> df.printSchema() 
> |-- COL1: offsetdatetimeudt (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of df.printSchema() to your question?

Comment: is this what you looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38610559/convert-spark-dataframe-column-to-python-list just convert df to string is kind pointless since it is an entire column,

Comment: |-- COL1: offsetdatetimeudt (nullable = true) output of df.printSchema()

Comment: I need to convert each row to Date, therefore I need it to be a string.

Comment: Your column values look like this: `2019-07-07T00:00:00.000Z`?

Comment: yes @cronoik, exactly. In SQL I convert them to string and then to_date, I want to do the same with pyspark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straightforward to cast column directly to string

```
df2 = df.withColumn('COL1', df['COL1'].cast(StringType()))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it fails: AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'unix_timestamp(... I tried all these things, I just need to convert the column into string.

Comment: from pyspark.sql import functions as F, don't forget to import sql functions to your spark job. That causes issue with cannot resolve

Comment: Can anyone convert the single column into string?? I want to work on column of strings) isn't it too trivial?

Comment: I import all required functions

Comment: added cast to String in my answer, check str_col1 you can try it (My DF type has string by default, but it should work in your case)

Comment: no, it doesn't work: I need smt. like this: df.select('COL1').cast(StringType()) Can you help with that?

Comment: I removed all redundant code and just cast StringType for you, check it again in my answer