# Convert pyspark.sql.column.Column to numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to pyspark and don't yet have a full overview of the avl. methods. I want to get *unique values of a single column* of a pyspark dataframe. This approach doesn't work:

```
F.array_distinct(my_spark_df.my_column).???
```

Whatever `???`-function I try to apply to the column, `toPandas()`, `collect()`, `display()` etc., I get:

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

I also found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38610559/convert-spark-dataframe-column-to-python-list) which is similar, but didn't help in my case since I want to select only distinct values before collecting them.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want distinct values for `my_column` you can try:

```
my_spark_df.select('my_column').distinct().collect()
```

This will give `Row` objects

You can get the list of values by:

```
distinct_vals = my_spark_df.select('my_column').distinct().collect()
distinct_vals = [a[my_column] for a in distinct_vals]
```

Comment: This gives a list of Row-objects. Actually don't know what to do with them either

Answer (score 1):

Directly after posting my question, I had another idea and it worked :)

Seems I was on the wrong track. The column-functions are probably the wrong approach here, instead we need to keep the dataframe, do the operations there and *then* we have the `toPandas()` method available:

```
my_spark_df.select("my_column").distinct().toPandas()
```